# Difference in jQuery of different elements created from a foreach

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem that I can't solve because I don't know enough about JS or jQuery.

I made a fiddle in order to illustrate a little bit what I've got
http://jsfiddle.net/2TvAq/12/

So I have a foreach which will create a table that displays tournament for each tournament. (The fiddle is just an example of what I want to do)

And I have also a link "+more infos" which must display only the div with the description of the clicked tournament.

I have no idea how to do it, how to make a difference between one tournament or another.

Also, what I put in the div content is

```
<?php
<div style="display:none" class="ContentInfos">'.  $tournoi->getDescription() 
?>
```

but, the description is html code as text in the database, so I have html as plaintext in my div, if you also know a way to execute html tags instead it would be great, the only solution I got is this :

```
<?php
echo '<div style="display:none; text-align:left;" class="moreinfos"></div>
<div style="display:none" class="ContentInfos">'. $tournoi->getDescription() .'</div>'?>
```

And in the script :

```
$('.moreinfos').html($('.ContentInfos').text());
```

I know that it is ugly but I can't figure any other way to display it correctly.

Tell me if I'm not clear enough, I have difficulties to explain it.
Thank you for the time you take to help me!

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you want .. but you can use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to toggle that particular `div` only (in the fiddle)

example with your fiddle

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).siblings('.content').toggle();
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/2TvAq/13/).

**this will work if your `a clickme` class  and  `div content` is inside same container**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's what I want, but it doesn't work when I try to apply it in my code, but anyway, it's the way I have to use so thank you, it helped me :)

Comment: Ok I didn't see that it has to be in the same container but I have my div in a different table row so it doesn't work, I updated the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2TvAq/15/). I hope you still know how to fix it!

Comment: use this one: $(this).parent().next('.content').toggle();

Comment: Thank you! :)
For the next one in my case, the fiddle from skparwal is [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/2TvAq/16/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();        
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
});
```

I have updated you fiddle.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/2TvAq/14/)

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to make it work but I don't know why it doesn't. But anyway, it helped me so tahnk you!

Comment: Well, it doesn't work because it isn't in the same container in the real code :/